# jquery .CSS() doesn't work, unable to change table display to "none"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting a simple CSS change on button click. It doesn't work, and it drives me crazy!

```
<input type="button" value="remove table" id="toggle" />
        <table id="t">
...
</table>
```

I built a simple JQ:

```
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
        if ($("#toggle").val() == "remove table") {
            $("#t").CSS("display", "none");
            $("#toggle").val("restore table")}
        else {
            $("#toggle").val("remove table");
            $("#t").css("display", "initial");
        }

    });
```

I placed the JQ at the end, right before closing the body.

I have no idea why id doesn't work.
It's simple, clean, meant to do the work without too many shortcuts/complications so that my teacher can see exactly what I did...

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working if you spell css in lowercase. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqa3kc2d/1/)

```
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    if ($("#toggle").val() == "remove table") {
        $("#t").css("display", "none");  // <-- Replaced here '.CSS' with '.css'
        $("#toggle").val("restore table");
    } else {
        $("#toggle").val("remove table");
        $("#t").css("display", "initial");
    }
});
```

Also, for your specific use case, I suggest you to look at the jQuery `toggle` function. This function will *display or hide the matched elements*. Therefore, no need to play with the strings `remove table` and `restore table` like you did.

With the `toggle` function, the code will be simply the following :

```
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    $("#t").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Also I used the .toggleClass() function in an earlier version and swiched to this one when it didn't work ;)

Comment: `toggle` and `toggleClass` are different functions. The former will toggle the display of an element, whereas the latter will add or remove a class on it

Comment: You must have a problem in a part that is not in the question. Which version of jQuery do you use? Also, to make sure the click handler is added when the button is indeed in the document, you could try wrapping the above code with `$(function() { // Code here });`

Comment: So I managed to create the function...
But now it seems that it only works if I put in inside the page, it doesn't read from my external .js page (other functions on the same HTML page work normally, so I know it's not a broken link...)

Comment: Right, so the problem seems to be where the script is...
When it was at the bottom of the page it worked. In the external .js file it only worked when I placed it out side the .ready() function for some reason...
Anyway, I just left it there and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$("#t").show();` and `$("#t").hide();`

But, I think it's not working because it's upper case. " `$("#t").CSS("display", "none");`" to `$("#t").css("display", "none");`

Answer (score 0):

CSS () method is undifined so replace
`$("#t").CSS("display", "none");` by `$("#t").css("display", "none");`

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, the .CSS wasn't the problem (I'm not sure WHAT was...)
But eventually I simply wrote a .toggle() code based on an "onclick" HTML event and it works great!:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove Table" id="toggle" onclick="toggle()"/>
```

And the JS:

```
function toggle() {
            $("#t").toggle();
            if ($("#toggle").val() == "Remove Table") {
                $("#toggle").val("Restore Table")
            }
            else {
                $("#toggle").val("Remove Table")
            }
        };
```

Simple and clean! Thanx Michael P.!

Answer (score -1):

1.try using {display:flex} instead of using {display:visible}

Comment: "visible" is a value of `visibility` not `display` and `table`s usually don't use flexbox.